# altium designer - Could not find port 'PA0' on model 'tm4c1294_01' for pin 'PA0'

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, pcb-design, altium

I am designing my very first PCB. I need a PCB with a cortex M4 core in a qtf package. I tried to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0n6k6GYu_V0&index=2&list=LLwe2piHB5wGY6Mycs0n3TZg

But get the following error when compiling at the end:

[Error] tm4c1294ncpdt.SchLib    Compiler    tm4c1294xl_01: Could not find port 'PA0' on model 'tm4c1294_01' for pin 'PA0'

Where did I do the error and/or how can I solve it?

Here you have a preview of the schematic and footprint I made.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **'Designator'** fields on the schematic symbol **pins** have to agree with the pads on the footprint. Otherwise, how would the program know where the pin numbers are on the footprint?

You can make the 'Display Name' whatever you like- it's just for human use.

Where you have PA0 etc. one would normally have the physical pin number, matching exactly the pin numbers on the footprint.

You can fix it by editing each of the schematic pins, and that should do it, if your footprint is numbered correctly.

Comment: Is this what you mean: http://imgur.com/B6B9LB0 ? I just repositionned all the pins. 32 pins on each sides just like the footprint. Btw just noticed I was missing plenty of pins... All the power pins. I copy pasted all the pins from the gpio sheets (743- 746) .But didn't find in the datasheet which part exactly said which pins were used for vcc and gnd. http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/spms433b/spms433b.pdf

Comment: Just found that the actual table I need to use starts on page 1773

Comment: Oh, about halfway through then, lol. The pin position on the symbol isn't what matters - the outside of the block should have the physical pin/pad numbers eg. 23 or whatever rather than PA0 etc.

Comment: I did what you said and that works! But the issue is that my component is huge: http://imgur.com/ql7MfMm. How am I supposed to make it fit now?

Comment: @JaqcuesMartin bigger sheet .. Or split the symbol up into pieces and distribute over multiple sheets or both.

Comment: Do I really need to put it on the scheme as a square? I'd really prefere a rectangle like so: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spmu365b/spmu365b.pdf (page 36)
Like I tried in the beginning but which generated a lot of errors

Comment: Any shape you like- or break it into several rectangles.

Comment: A very last question if I may: how do you change the size of you sheet? Can't find it

Comment: Tools->Document Options->Size (change to C, D, E or whatever)